# Excel Macro check if cell is empty and search specific word in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, is-empty

Guy, I am beginner for VBA language, and I have a question to stuck on it.

How to make a macro script to check if **ANY** rows of column B is input word of "C" AND **ANY** rows of column C is empty, then it will trigger to highlight this row with color and prompt up the message box to remind user to correct it.

Also, the column D is using the formula and cell by cell method to check the above requirement.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B4),"",IF(OR(B4="C",B4="O"),IF(AND(B4="C", ISBLANK(C4)),"WARNING: Case Closed! Please Write Down Resolution!",""),"ERROR: Invalid Value - Status! Please Input The Right Value!"))
```

For example, the row 4 meet up requirement and affected.

Is there way to do so?
Please help. Thanks.

[image: Pic]

---

**UPDATE:Thanks Variatus!**

When I save the file, it prompt up this message box. What can I do? Thanks.

**Macro Screen**

[image: screen]

**Error**

[image: error]

Comment: Having added a macro to your workbook, it must now be saved in XLSM format If you press "Yes" in response to the message you posted the code will not be saved and its functionality therefore lost. Click *SaveAs* and save the workbook as macro-enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances you would be asked to show more of an own effort before receiving help on this forum, including from me. But apparently circumstances aren't normal. So, here we go. Paste this procedure to a standard code module (it's name would be a variation of *Module1* by default).

```
Option Explicit

Sub MarkErrors()
    ' 283
    
    Dim Spike()         As String
    Dim i               As Long                 ' index of Spike
    Dim Rl              As Long                 ' last used row
    Dim R               As Long                 ' loop counter: rows

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheet1                                 ' this is the sheet's CodeName (change to suit)
        .UsedRange.Interior.Pattern = xlNone    ' remove all existing highlights
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim Spike(1 To Rl)
        For R = 2 To Rl
            If Trim(.Cells(R, "B").Value) = "C" Then
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(R, "C")) Then
                    .Range(.Cells(R, "A"), .Cells(R, "D")).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    i = i + 1
                    Spike(i) = "Row " & R
                End If
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If i Then
        ReDim Preserve Spike(1 To i)
        MsgBox "Status errors were found in the following entries:-" & vbCr & _
               Join(Spike, "," & vbCr), vbInformation, "Corrections required"
    End If
End Sub
```

Pay attention to the specified worksheet `Sheet1`. This is a *CodeName*, and it is a default. Excel will create a sheet by that name when you create a workbook. The *CodeName* doesn't change when the user changes the tab name but you can change it in the VB Editor. It's the `(Name)` property of the worksheet.

Install the procedure below in the code sheet of `Sheet1` (not a standard code module and therefore not the same as where you installed the above code. This module is created by Excel for each sheet in every workbook. Use the existing one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 283
    MarkErrors
End Sub
```

This is an event procedure. It will run automatically whenever `Sheet1` is activated (selected). So, under normal circumstances you shouldn't ever need to run the first procedure manually. But I've already talked about circumstances. They aren't always normal. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your big help. But is it possible to make it automate? And now, I need to manual to run a macro every time to execute it. Thanks.

Comment: The macro `MarkErrors` will run automatically whenever you switch to view another worksheet and back. If your workbook only has one sheet, add a `Workbook_Open` event procedure to the `ThisWorkbook` module and call the procedure from there (just like the `Worksheet_Activate` procedure but another name in another module). You may also hitch the process to to a `Worksheet_Change` event but that is outside the scope of this question because it would run only when one cell is modified.